Ubuntu 24.04 randomly disconnects, "Activation of network connection failed" loop
How do I stop this? I am using an Asus Vivobook Go 15 so my WiFi card is an RTL8821CE.
sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager is too big to output here so the pastebin is here: https://pastebin.com/YybjATXx
service NetworkManager status outputs:
● NetworkManager.service - Network Manager
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/NetworkManager.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Wed 2024-07-17 22:07:57 PDT; 18h ago
       Docs: man:NetworkManager(8)
   Main PID: 880 (NetworkManager)
      Tasks: 4 (limit: 8991)
     Memory: 18.5M (peak: 34.0M)
        CPU: 6.858s
     CGroup: /system.slice/NetworkManager.service
             └─880 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

Jul 18 16:24:37 etcetera-Vivobook-Go-E1504GAB-E1504GA NetworkManager[880]: <info>  [1721345077.8768] Config: added 'psk' value '<hidden>'
Jul 18 16:24:38 etcetera-Vivobook-Go-E1504GAB-E1504GA NetworkManager[880]: <info>  [1721345078.3398] device (wlp1s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Jul 18 16:24:42 etcetera-Vivobook-Go-E1504GAB-E1504GA NetworkManager[880]: <info>  [1721345082.4412] device (wlp1s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Jul 18 16:24:42 etcetera-Vivobook-Go-E1504GAB-E1504GA NetworkManager[880]: <info>  [1721345082.4476] device (wlp1s0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
Jul 18 16:24:42 etcetera-Vivobook-Go-E1504GAB-E1504GA NetworkManager[880]: <info>  [1721345082.4521] device (wlp1s0): supplicant interface state: associating -> associated
Jul 18 16:24:42 etcetera-Vivobook-Go-E1504GAB-E1504GA NetworkManager[880]: <info>  [1721345082.4757] device (wlp1s0): supplicant interface state: associated -> 4way_handshake
Jul 18 16:24:42 etcetera-Vivobook-Go-E1504GAB-E1504GA NetworkManager[880]: <info>  [1721345082.4897] device (wlp1s0): supplicant interface state: 4way_handshake -> completed
Jul 18 16:24:42 etcetera-Vivobook-Go-E1504GAB-E1504GA NetworkManager[880]: <info>  [1721345082.4898] device (wlp1s0): Activation: (wifi) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) successful. Connected to wireless network "NETGEAR54"
Jul 18 16:24:42 etcetera-Vivobook-Go-E1504GAB-E1504GA NetworkManager[880]: <info>  [1721345082.4902] device (wlp1s0): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jul 18 16:24:42 etcetera-Vivobook-Go-E1504GAB-E1504GA NetworkManager[880]: <info>  [1721345082.4913] dhcp4 (wlp1s0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)

service --status-all outputs:
 [ - ]  alsa-utils
 [ - ]  anacron
 [ + ]  apparmor
 [ + ]  apport
 [ + ]  bluetooth
 [ - ]  clamav-freshclam
 [ - ]  console-setup.sh
 [ + ]  cron
 [ + ]  cups
 [ + ]  dbus
 [ + ]  gdm3
 [ - ]  grub-common
 [ + ]  kerneloops
 [ - ]  keyboard-setup.sh
 [ + ]  kmod
 [ - ]  lightdm
 [ + ]  lm-sensors
 [ + ]  openvpn
 [ - ]  plymouth
 [ + ]  plymouth-log
 [ + ]  procps
 [ - ]  rsync
 [ - ]  saned
 [ - ]  speech-dispatcher
 [ - ]  spice-vdagent
 [ - ]  sssd
 [ + ]  sysstat
 [ + ]  ufw
 [ + ]  unattended-upgrades
 [ - ]  uuidd
 [ - ]  whoopsie
 [ - ]  x11-common


Please edit the question and add exactly what you have tried and what errors or messages you got. This way anyone trying to help will not be telling you to do something you have already tried.

@David It is in the question, it says that I tried installing Mainline and that I also tried installing drivers. I didn't get any errors, these solutions just didn't work.

The question says you were told to install Mainline not that you did. Same with the unnamed drivers, you say told to install but not that you did.

Look at the network logs with the terminal command: sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager.  Also do: service NetworkManager status and service --status-all.

Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Take the [tour].

@waltinator Added more details to the question. Also switched from Xubuntu to Ubuntu so edited that.

Don't post pictures of text. They're unscrollable, lines are truncated, can't be Copy/Pasted as part of an Answer, invisible to AskUbuntu's search, and aren't the Good Way of adding text to your Question. See askubuntu.com/help/formatting

@waltinator I wasn't posting pictures, I was using Pastebin, a website where you upload text.
